figurecanvasagg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import easyocr
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def ox_photo(filepath : str):
    img = cv2.imread(filepath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    img_filter = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 15, 15)
    edges = cv2.Canny(img_filter, 30, 200)

    cont = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cont = imutils.grab_contours(cont)
    cont = sorted(cont, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    pos = None
    for c in cont:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 10, True)

        if len(approx) == 4:
            pos = approx
            break

    mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, np.uint8)
    new_img = cv2.drawContours(mask, [pos], 0, 255, -1)
    bitwise_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    (z, v) = np.where(mask == 255)
    (z1, v1) = (np.min(z), np.min(v))
    (z2, v2) = (np.max(z), np.max(v))
    crop = gray[z1:z2, v1:v2]

    text = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
    text = text.readtext(crop)

    res = text[0][-2]
    final_image = cv2.putText(img, res, (z1, v2 - 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 5, (255, 255, 255), 5)
    final_image = cv2.rectangle(img, (v1, z1), (v2, z2), (0, 255, 0), 5)

    pl.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(final_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    pl.show()

def open_image():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Выберите картинку", filetypes=[("Image Files", ".jpg .jpeg .png .bmp")])
    if filepath:
        ox_photo(filepath)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Выбор картинки")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Выберите картинку:")
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Обзор", command=open_image)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()

I create an .exe file with pythoninstaller, and after starting it I get a warning:

figurecanvasagg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown after

Can anyone help with that?
I've tried to install PyQt6 and made an .exe file one more time, but that doesn't work.
